# WebView Video Embed

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to play video inside my webview. I have examined different example but my HTML a bit different.

```
{\"mp4\":[{\"name\":\"240\",\"file\":\"http:\\\/\\\/xxxx.xxxx.net\\\/lt\\\/2016\\\/04\\\/24\\\/test_320x240.mp4\",\"type\":\"video\\\/mp4\"}
```

I can download HTML code and used function;

```
webview.loadData(myHTML,"text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);)
```

However, I can't display videos in my application. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing the video using VideoView rather than trying to load it in a webview.Below is the sample code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "rhyme.mp4");
    videoView.setVideoPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.start();
}
```

Also if you want to stream some video files from internet, you can go ahead with **ExoPlayer**. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821472/how-to-use-android-exoplayer)
Kindly mark this reply as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks but that not the solution that I expect. I've improve my solution a bit by using webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(). Now I can see videos in webview but I have problems about playing it.